# How can I have the nodes grouped in descending order and the nodes in ascending order?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view listing articles grouped by year (on the post date) which returns me a HTML list like this.

```
2018

- Article Feb 01, 2018
- Article Jan 05, 2018

2017 

- Article Dec 01, 2017
- Article Nov 05, 2017
- Article Oct 03, 2017
- Article Sep 05, 2017
```

The years are correctly sorted in descending order, but I would like to have the nodes of each year sorted in ascending order, as in the following list.

```
2018
- Article Jan 05, 2018
- Article Feb 01, 2018

2017
- Article Jan 10, 2017
- Article Oct 03, 2017
- Article Nov 05, 2017
- Article Dec 01, 2017
```

I have tried to apply an ascending sort on the content, but it also affects the years.

I have also checked [Views: how to ASC sort the grouping field #1 and sort DESC its content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71767/views-how-to-asc-sort-the-grouping-field-1-and-sort-desc-its-content), but I don't want to add an extra field for the year.

I have also tried the solution posted on [Views, Group By, can't specify order?](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2009-08-15/views-group-by-cant-specify-order#comment-7122090) but it didn't work for me.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x)

```
function MODULENAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
   //print_r($view->query->orderby);
  if ($view->name == 'VIEWNAME') {
  // check the position on the orderBy function in the query
  // For this you can check the values with print_r() function.
   $view->query->orderby[0]['direction'] = "ASC";
  }
}
```